NewRelic (newrelic-react-native-agent) PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy issue on Appstore submission
I have integrated NewRelic plugin (newrelic-react-native-agent) within my React Native app, the app works fine locally as well as on Testflight, but when I submit the app for Apple review on Appstore, it fails with below message -
Hello,

We noticed one or more issues with a recent submission for App Store review for the following app:

Neuroglee Health
Version 2.3.4
Build 10
Please correct the following issues and upload a new binary to App Store Connect.

ITMS-91056: Invalid privacy manifest - The PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy file from the following path is invalid: "Frameworks/NewRelic.framework/PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy". Keys and values in any privacy manifest must be in a valid format. For more details about privacy manifest files, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files.

Apple Developer Relations

I already have PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy in my app, but how can I modify 3rd party SDK .xcprivacy file? Any help appreciated.
I've tried changing the .xcprivacy file from newrelic-react-native-agent Framework, but that didn't helped.

which version you have of newrelic-react-native-agent ?

I tried the latest version (1.3.7), but that was crashing for me, then I tried the version in the example they provided. 1.3.4, it worked but Appstore submission failed.

i think you need to disable flipper plugin in Pod file. it might works !
comment all flipper configuration.

@Pankaj is this for 1.3.7 ? What about PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy issue ?

you need to check your privacy manifest format, check this : https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/react-native/data-management/apple-privacy-manifest/
